# Out of 100 bicycles, ten bicycles have puncture. What is the probability of not having any punctured bicycle in a sample of 5 bicycles?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Out of 100 bicycles, ten bicycles have puncture. What is the probability of not having any punctured bicycle in a sample of 5 bicycles ?

(1) $\frac{1}{10^5}$ 
(2) $\frac{1}{2^5}$  (3)  $\frac{1}{2^9}$ 
(4)   $\frac{9^5}{10^5}$

My approach is as follow
I randomly select the following

A) 1 defective 4 non defective
$^{10}C_1*^{90}C_4*=25551900$

B) 2 defective 3 non defective
$^{10}C_2*^{90}C_3*=5286600$

C) 3 defective 2 non defective
$^{10}C_3*^{90}C_2*=480600$

D) 4 defective 1 non defective
$^{10}C_4*^{90}C_1*=18900$

E) 5 defective 0 non defective
$^{10}C_5*^{90}C_0*=252$

Total Non-favorable Cases=31338252

Total number of cases=$^{100}C_5=75287520$

Total number of favorable Cases =$1-\frac{31338252}{75287520}=0.58375 $

Where as the value of $\frac{9^5}{10^5}=0.59049$, which is slightly different .

Based on the option choice I would like to know whether I am making any mistake.

Comment: You are assuming that there are only 100 cycles in total. The question assumed there are a large number, so that the chance of any given cycle having a puncture is always 1/10.

Comment: Yes, the question is badly posed. 10 out of any 100 have a puncture so the probability that one random have a puncture is 1/10

Comment: @almagest The way the problem is written, I would actually have thought there were 100 bikes in a shed, ten of them had puncture, and you're taking five of them out for inspection (or something to that effect). The answer choices, on the other hand, show that this is not what the problem author was thinking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question of sampling "with replacement" and "without replacement."

The way you have done it is without replacement a based on the phrasing of the question the correct answer.

$P = \frac {90\choose 5}{100\choose 5} =\frac {110983}{190120}\approx0.53$

Sampling with replacement, after we find a bike without a puncture, we put it back in the rack, and ask someone else to choose the second bike to test, and it might be the same bike.

$P = 0.9^5$

This will give a higher probability of finding all puncture free bikes as you have the chance to find the same puncture free bike multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

sampling with replacement: 0.9x0.9x0.9x0.9x0.9                                                sampling without replacement: 90C5 x 10C0 /100C5 = 90!x95!/(85!x100!)